# Xcode - Vertical Stack of Horizontal Stacks constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm very new to using Interface Builder and Auto Layout so please bear with me.

I'm trying to lay out a vertical stack of horizontal stacks, with each horizontal stack being made up of a label and another horizontal stack of two labels. The whole vertical stack is wrapped in another view that has 10 points left and right constraints. I want the two stack elements of each horizontal stack to be at the edges of the stack.

I can get the layout to look how I want it on the interface builder but when I run it, the Sunrise AM/PM label gets cut off.

[Storyboard next to simulator instance where AM label is truncated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPsyi.png)

[View hierarchy with constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOEDU.png)

Please let me know if there's anything unclear about what my goal or my issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that your programm does need to truncate something to fit everything on the screen. Since you probably did not define which element to truncate (by altering the compression resistance) it takes the last one in the stack - the am/pm one. Changing the compression resistance should fix this.

Check out [this guide](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef) to learn about it.